# Place to purchase America the Beautiful Pass in Page (AZ) open on weekdays, or in Las Vegas on Sunday?

Tags: usa, tickets, national-parks

I'm arriving in Las Vegas on Saturday night, staying for the night, and then driving to Page on Sunday.  I'll be staying in Page from Sunday night onwards, and visiting the various attractions near Page starting Monday, such as the Vermilion Cliffs and the Grand Canyon (North Rim), which are covered by the America the Beautiful Pass.

I would like to purchase the pass.  There is this site that tells me where the pass can be bought (https://store.usgs.gov/s3fs-public/PassIssuanceList.pdf), but it appears that many of them do not open on Sunday (if there are any, I would be able to to drop by any of them on the drive from Las Vegas to Page).  It furthermore seems that Page doesn't have an office or nearby National Recreation Area (NRA) site or office to purchase the pass.  While the list contains the Grand Canyon, it isn't clear whether it means only the (more touristy) South Rim, or the North Rim as well.  There's also Glen Canyon, but that's a huge area and it doesn't say which entrances I can use to purchase the pass either.

Where is the most convenient place for me to buy the pass?

Note: I'm not visiting any NRA sites on Sunday.

Comment: I've probably owned 10 of those passes and I've always just bought them at park entrances. Most places that have enough manpower for access control will have a booth or visitor center selling them.

Comment: @ex-user3761894 Most, not all.  I have entered Death Valley at crossings with nothing but a machine that accepts payment, I have entered Death Valley at a place where there isn't even any way to pay.  (Legally, you need a park pass to enter that way.)

Answer (score 5):

That list of places is only government places.  My last two passes came from REI and the website still lists it for sale.  There are two stores in Las Vegas, but none between here and Page so you would have to stick around to 10am when they open.

You can also buy a pass at many park entrances.

Answer (score 4):

I drove to Page without getting the pass on the way, in the hope of getting it from the Carl Hayden Visitor Center (just outside of Page) on Monday.

When I got there, they told me to drive to the Wahweep entrance to the Glen Canyon NRA, which was just a short distance away, to get the pass from the toll booth there.  They were correct - there was a manned toll booth there where I purchased the America the Beautiful pass.

So yes - you may not be able to buy the pass within Page city limits, but a short drive to the Wahweep entrance of the Glen Canyon NRA will allow you to purchase the pass.